# Widget redirecting to home page

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, widgets, plugins-url

Am trying to create a widget that searches for names. The searching and all that is fine, but when I hit submit, I get returned to the front page. I tried messing with the action="", but no matter what I change it to, the widget still redirects to the home page.

Am sure it's simple, I just can't figure out what am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated!

```
    <?php
    require_once('include/functions.php'); 

   if( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) { exit;}

   class HNDomainSearchWidget extends WP_Widget 
   {
function HNDomainSearchWidget() 
{
    $widget_ops = array(
        'classname' => 'HNDomainSearchWidget',
        'description' => 'Search for domains on your site.'
    );
    $this->WP_Widget('HNDomainSearchWidget', 'HobiNom Domain Search', $widget_ops);
}

// admin form, in the widget page
function form($instance)
{
    global $wpdb;
    (isset($wpdb->base_prefix) ? $_prefix = $wpdb->base_prefix : $_prefix = $wpdb->prefix); 

$instance = wp_parse_args( (array) $instance, array( 'title' => '' ) );
$title = $instance['title'];
    // allow for updating the widget name
    ?>
   <p>
        <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>">Title: 
        <input class="wide" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo attribute_escape($title); ?>" />
    </label></p>
    <?php
    }

function widget($args, $instance) 
{ 
    global $wpdb;
    global $post;

    $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

    // widget sidebar output
    extract( $args );
    // these are the widget options
    $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
    $text = $instance['text'];
    echo $before_widget;

    // Display the widget
    echo '<div class="widget-text wp_widget_plugin_box">';

    // Check if title is set
    if ( $title ) { echo $before_title . $title . $after_title;}

    // the actual search get_permalink( $post->ID ); 
    $pid = (isset($post->ID)) ? get_permalink($post->ID) : '';
    //echo '<form role="search" method="get" id="domainsearch" action="' . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . '?search_for_domain" >';
    echo '<form role="search" method="get" id="domainsearch" action="'. $pid .'" >';
    echo '<input type="text" name="domain" value="Domain.com" onfocus="this.value = \'\';" />';
    echo '<input type="submit" value="' . __( 'Search' ) . '" name="search_domain" /><br />';
    echo '</div></form>';

    $this->search_for_domain($_GET['domain'], get_permalink( $post->ID ));

    echo $after_widget;
}

// update widget options
function update($new_instance, $old_instance) 
{
    $instance = $old_instance;
    // Fields
    $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
    return $instance;
}

function deactivate()
{
     delete_option('HNDomainSearchWidget');
    }


// process the widget input and search for domain using
function search_for_domain($search_domain, $permalink)
{
    $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];

    if(isset($search_domain))
    {
        // get details to access
        $hobinom = new hobinom_db(); 

        $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();
        $details = $hobinom->get_details($current_user_id);

        $username = $details['username'];  
        $password = $details['password']; 

        // separate the data from domain and tld
        // explode makes each subsequent . a new array, so domain.co.uk is [0],[1],[2] while domain.co is [0][1]
        $root_domain = explode(".", $search_domain);
        $domain = $root_domain[0]; 
        $tld = substr($search_domain, strrpos($search_domain, ".")+1);

        // access enom api
        $url =  '/interface.asp?command=check&sld='.$domain.'&tld='.$tld.
                '&responsetype=xml&uid='.$username.'&w='.$password;

        // Load the API results into a SimpleXML object
        $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

        if(isset($xml->errors)) 
        {
            // print all errors
            function recursive_print($item, $key)
            {
                echo '<div id="domain-notavail">'.$item.'</div><br />';
            }
            array_walk_recursive($xml->errors, 'recursive_print');
        }
        else
        {
            // Read the results
            $rrpCode = $xml->RRPCode;
            $rrpText = $xml->RRPText;

            // Perform actions based on results
            switch ($rrpCode) 
            {
                case 210:
                    echo '<div id="domain-avail">'. $xml->DomainName.' is available</div>';
                    break;
                case 211:
                    echo '<div id="domain-notavail">'.$xml->DomainName.' is not available</div>';
                    break;
                default:
                    echo '<div id="domain-default">Code: '. $rrpCode . ' ' . $rrpText . '</div>';
                    break;
            }
        }       
        //$this->hobinom_redirect($referrer);
    }
}

function hobinom_redirect($permalink) 
{
    wp_redirect($permalink);
}
    }

 add_action('widgets_init', array($HNDomainSearchWidget, 'hobinom_redirect'));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a guess but if the search works but returns you to the home page it sounds like `get_permalink( $post->ID )` is not giving you the right values. Look at the page source to confirm. That implies that `$post` is not set, or not accessible, so put `global $post;` in your function before you try to use that variable. I'd suggest something like this right at the top of your function:

```
global $post;
$pid = (isset($post->ID)) ? get_permalink($post->ID) : '';
```

Then use `$pid` instead of `$post->ID` after that.

To the extent that I can test that widget (It calls a class I don't have and the URL to the actual domain search is only partial.) it is operating mostly as expected. This...

```
  $p = get_queried_object();
  $pid = (isset($p->ID)) ? get_permalink($p->ID) : home_url();
```

... will get you a little bit better results than the previous block but you are actually redirecting to `$referer`-- `$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];`-- not to that permalink anyway. In context, it is a bit confusing what you are trying to do at all.

I don't understand the way you have the widget "registered". I got an error until I altered the last few lines to :

```
function register_HND_widget() {
  register_widget('HNDomainSearchWidget');
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'register_HND_widget');
```

Also, you should really have [debugging enabled](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress). That code generates a fair number of `Notice`s.

Comment: I changed to just $pid, and the URL becomes: http://localhost/wordpress/3.5.1/1?search (which is a 404)
If I change it to get_permalink($pid), then it again redirects to the front page.

Comment: Was having edit problems. Kept pressing enter for a new line, instead it kept saving while I was still typing. :)

Comment: @Hybride : See the edit. If `$post` is set correctly and `get_permalink` is giving you the wrong URL, something is broken.

Comment: Your edit did not work, it sent me back to the homepage.

Comment: Post all of your widget.

Comment: I tried modifying the code to include the updated url - it shows me the correct results when am on the page, but still redirects me to the home page. Am simply trying to have the submit button run the query but still stay on the same page it was submit on - that is, don't redirect at all. Just run the query and return to the page it was queried on with the result.

Answer (score 0):

I switched the method="post" and the action="" (rather than get/and a url). For some reason, that fixed it. Am not sure why "get" was having such a hard time, as it still continued to redirect if I switched back the method.

Regardless, thank you to s_ha_dum for trying to help.